# DacServices ExportBacpac Exception with Windows Users

Tags: c#, sql-server, dac

I'm using the Data-tier Application Framework (DACFx) in an attempt to export schema and data from a subset of the tables in my database.

```
var dacServices = new DacServices(connectionString);
dacServices.ExportBacpac("database.bacpac", database, tables);
```

I know there are some limitations on what is supported, and I've addressed the issues that had to do with the code (stored procedures, etc). However, I've hit a block with Windows Users/Logins. I'm not sure how I can get around it.

The exception details:

```
One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71564: The element User: [Domain\User] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71564: The element Login: [Domain\User] has property IsMappedToWindowsLogin set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
```

I realize Windows Authentication is not supported in Azure SQL. **But is there not an option to simply ignore Users, Logins, etc.?**

I've read various posts that claim you can just DROP the logins and users. and then re-CREATE them following the export. Unfortunately, I can't do that in my case since these objects are being used for active connections. I've also read that some people solved this by doing backup/restore and then dropping the users on the secondary. That could potentially work but surely there's a better way with less effort.

De-compiling the code, I can see where the ExportBacpac method creates:

```
DacExtractOptions extractOptions = new DacExtractOptions()
      {
        EnforceSqlAzureRestrictions = true,
        IgnorePermissions = false,
        VerifyExtraction = true,
        ExtractNonApplicationDatabaseScopedElements = true
      };
```

Of course, this is all private, internal, etc. Shame, I'd like to turn EnfoceSqlAzureRestrictions off!

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at using a publish profile and SQLPAckage.exe. You can use the advanced options to excldue users and logins from being published https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ssdt/new-advanced-publish-options-to-specify-object-types-to-exclude-or-not-drop/

Comment: Hello, I am answering a bit late but the issue is still present (in my case for an "orphaned" login) and there's no obvious option to skip logins (which I don't care, I just need tables). Did you find a solution please John ?